# Comparing 2 files

Tags: scripting, diff, file-comparison

I have the need via a script to compare 2 files contents and if the contents are different then execute another script however is the contents are the same do nothing. I've tried using the DIFF command but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone offer a simple way to perform this feat?

Comment: How exactly did you try to use `diff`? in what way didn't it work?

Comment: Use a hash tool instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `diff` or `cmp`. For straight comparisons I prefer `cmp`:

```
cmp -s "$file1" "$file2" || otherscript.sh
```

Comment: Where would the otherscript.sh file be located? I executed the command in the terminal command from the default director, i.e. /home/username, not such file appeared.

Comment: @gimmegimme let me turn this around: what do you want to do when the two files are not the same?

Answer (score 2):

`diff file1 file2` will accomplish exactly what you have asked (though I suspect you are actually trying to accomplish something more advanced than what you have described). `diff` will return a 0 exit status if they files are identical, and a non-zero exit status if they differ. You probably want to redirect the output if this is being used in a script so it doesn't print out the differences.

```
if ! diff "$file1" "$file2" > /dev/null; then
    # test evaluated to False (1), so the files are different
    bash otherscript.sh
fi
```

Comment: Adding the `-q` (`--brief`) option will make `diff` only report if files differ and it will stop when the first difference is found, so it can be a lot faster in many cases.

Answer (score -1):

Use a hash instead:

```
HASH_VALUE_1=$(sha1sum file1 | cut -c 1-40)
HASH_VALUE_2=$(sha1sum file2 | cut -c 1-40)
if [[ "$HASH_VALUE_1" == "$HASH_VALUE_2" ]]
then
    # your code
else
    # your code
fi
```

The above is coded for bash.

Comment: In this situation a hash is actually worse. Both `diff` and `sha1sum` have to read the files in full, but there is a small statistical chance that the hash comparison could return a match for two different files. Not so with `diff` (or `cmp`).

Comment: `diff` is worse, as it has to compute the difference, not just check if they are equal. Using a cryptographic hash is probably much worse still (cryptographic hashes are expensive to compute, as they are supposed to make it extremely difficult to fake a file with a given hash)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare text files, the side-by-side option is useful for displaying differences. Use

```
diff -y -a <filea> <fileb>
```

then (-y denotes an ascii file).

If you just need to know if the files are different in ANY byte (binary), then use

```
diff -q <file1> <file2>
```

In any case, diff returns 0 if the files are identical.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question